# Increase LOGIN session with PHP

Tags: php, session, google-oauth

I am in a conodrum here. I have an application that uses Google OAuth and the requirement is to increase the time a user stays logged in.

At the beginning of the script that is called by the front controller (index.php) there is an if statement that checks for an existance of the global variable $_SESSION.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) @session_start();
```

This is all fine as I can see the session data for the logged in user. Now I do not know exactly how to tackle this given that the google token data saved in the session also happens to have an `expires_in` key with a value of 3299 (an hour).

My analysis is that after an hour a session timesout from google and to control this such that it is extended I should be looking at updating the code that authenticates through to google to refresh the token offline. I am not really sure about this reason being I could always control the timing out of sessions within my application at least - the issue I am having is the how part. .

Below is a code snippet I wrote just above the @session_start call:

```
if(isset($_SESSION)){
    $sessionKeys = array(key1, key2,key3); //Keys that are destroyed on logout
    $refreshLifetime = false;
    foreach($sessionKeys as $key){
      if(!empty($_SESSION[$key]){
         $refreshLifetime = true;
       }
     }

   if($refreshLifetime){
       @setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() * 3600);
   }
 }
```

Something does not feel right about this code for all the complexities of handling sessions with PHP there could be together with how different operating systems treat sessions on PHP add to that client side and server side session handling.

Can somebody help me with an idea that I can tackle this issue such that the application can have an extended session say 5 hours before it times out?

## EDIT

I have decided to move the application session save path from `/var/lib/php5` to a directory within the application itself. I started of by setting the `session.gc_maxlifetime` to 10 minutes to see if I will be locked out or rather redirected to the login page but I am not.

I have added the `cache_expire` setting even though I was hesitant after reading [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php) and the first user note contributed there doesn't seem to link the use of cache expire with gc_lifetime.

If I were to put this in should it be the same as what I have set for the session.gc_maxlifetime?

```
ini_set('session.save_path', __DIR__ .'/../tmp');

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 300);

ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

session_cache_limiter('private'); 
session_cache_expire(300);
```

However, This did not work as I was expecting to be redirected back to the login page after 5 minute of inactivity within the application. Could there be something I am missing and this code is right at the top of the file where `session_start` is called.

Comment: Thanks at Ryan. Our work is based on Scrum and to me that sounds like a new feature. I could propose it but in the meantime the idea is to just prolong the session to X amount of hours or rather the users day shift. I have taken note of your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You have both [`gc-maxlifetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) and [`cache_expire`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-expire) session configuration which you can use to affect that behavior.

Don't use the `setcookie` function to do this.

Comment: Thanks I will do some googling and see if my problem gets solved.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestion and I do not seem to be kicked out after the time I have specified which was 10 minutes and reduced to 5 just for testing purposes. Mind giveng me some more insight onto this? How can I best use gc-maxlifetime and cache_expire?

Comment: On which OS you run this application? Some linux-servers disable the ability to use `session.gc_maxlifetime` and to the cleaning using a cronjob.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.... That is the same reason I decided to house my session content within the application because it was using /var/lib/php5 when I checked the storage path before putting this code in place. I wanted to have control of my session so that no other process wipes them  out.

Comment: The problem is that some of the servers set the `gc_maxlifetime` to `0`, and you can't change it.

Comment: Does that, then, mean I can not extend the session unless I use a different technique like "Remember me"? I am so sorry to be bombarding you with questions like this I am kind of stuck in here.

Comment: You might wanna check this directly from the config (and not from the php code).

Comment: Cool thanks. I will wait for the guys who have access to the production servers to come back in the meantime I will see if I can change it from within my development box which is the OS version I gave you above. Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work even when I literally increased the value of gc_maxlifetine in my php.ini file on Apache to 8 hours I was still logged out. I am not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that Google Login lasts for 3 hours and we use their API to authenticate. I still have to investigate more.